# Normality tests for latent variable in probit regression

Tags: normality-assumption, skewness, latent-variable, probit, kurtosis

I am performing a probit regression where the latent variable y* is conceptually important. I already have the model defined with regressors: categorical variables, quadratic terms, continuous variables and other integer variables. Now, I am in the post evaluation stage of the model, the average prediction performance is good 83%, apart from other tests that are satisfactory, but I also need to **test the normality** of the latent variable (error term), and its variance, that is: the heteroscedaticity, asymmetry and kurtosis. I have already reviewed substantive works such as Chesher1987 "Residual Analysis in the Grouped and Censored Normal Linear Model" and Bera1984 "Testing the Normality Assumption in Limited Dependent Variable Models", both of which develop LM tests using residual moments. That's very good. So I wanted to perform the tests but I couldn't find any package in R that includes those tests. ps.: I'm not very good with programming.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using different distributions and comparing their fits in terms of maximized likelihoods. That's not a statistical hypothesis test per se, but might be more relevant, especially if the goal is to find a good predictive model. In addition, hypothesis testing itself is a problematic enterprise.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. However, in my work I already defined the use of probit, and it works fine, so just for support purposes I need to test the assumption of normality of the error term.